# Deploy docker container to production with image of newer version without stopping the currently running container

Tags: docker, azure-devops, docker-compose

Production server do not tolerate the downtime when the container has to be updated with newer version. Currently, I have implemented the three steps:

1. Pull latest image from docker hub.
2. Stop and Remove currently running container.
3. Start the new container with latest version image.

**How can we have it done without stopping and removing the running container(for the ports).**

Comment: You need to provide more detail about the infrastructure on which the container is running. Are you using an Azure app service? Kubernetes? A virtual machine?

Comment: Also, what type of program is in the container? Is it a web application, a database or something other?

Comment: I am using the virtual machine for the application to be deployed. And the container has the web application in it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the issue using Azure App Service**.
For the detailed documentation, [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#Auto-Swap).

Rather than deploying directly into production, we are deploying it to a staging environment and once it is good, the swapping of the staging with the production takes place for zero downtime. Also in case of any issues in new production, the re-swap can bring back the older production from staging.